# when using putAll() for list of cache objects, Is it possible to retrieve the conflicted list of objects when getting TransactionOptimisticException

Tags: ignite

when using putAll() for the list of cache objects, Is it possible to retrieve the conflicted list of objects when getting TransactionOptimisticException? So that I can run my business logic only for those objects as it is a costly operation.As far as I checked TransactionOptimisticException.java, no possible way. But wanted to ask if there is another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no such possibility.